# Infinetly first-countable space?

Tags: calculus, general-topology

For $ℝ$ and for cofinite topology over $ℕ$ holds property, that for every deleted neighborhood $Oa$ and for every finite subset in X, there is another deleted neighborhood $Ua$ such that $Ua\subset Oa\setminus M$.

What is name of spaces where this property holds?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i think, i can take T1 connected space.  We take intersection of neighborhoods, separating poins of M from a, this intersection is finite, so open, so if it singleton - it's clopen.

Comment: It doesn't need to be a singleton. It is just an open neighborhood of $a$, disjoint from $M,$ and that is sufficient (you then intersect it with $Oa$ to get $Ua$)

Comment: I mean, intersecting with $Oa$ (deleted neighborhood) might be empty if there are clopen sets in topology.

Comment: For example, property holds for discrete topology. But i think it's already another question.

Comment: I don't think these 2 last comments are relevant. Even if "intersecting with the deleted neighborhood $Oa$ is empty", this empty $Ua$ *is* a solution. And the discrete topology *is* a T1 space. (Btw, I don't think that T1 spaces are called "T1-connected".)

Comment: .You are right.